# Website not displaying Unicode character

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, unicode

I'm having trouble with razor displaying unicode characters. When it loops through all the items in my model I would like a ✔ to appear everywhere fileID doesn't equal zero. I've tried this so far:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @(item.fileID == "0" ? "" : "&#x2714;")
    }
```

but it just seems to display &#x2714; instead of a check is there some other way I should be formatting this?

Comment: What is the value of the `Content-type` header at the browser? (Use your browser's developer tools to look at the HTTP headers.)

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">

Comment: actually there are two:
<meta charset="UTF-8">

Comment: It will display unicode if its not in part of razor expression.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the problem with the addition of Html.Raw that makes the page read the ternary statements response as normal HTML instead of as a string.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @( Html.Raw(item.fileID == "0" ? "" : "&#x2714;"))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@(item.fileID == "0" ? "" : "&#x2714;")
```

Razor will HTML-escape strings for you, so you should be writing plain text, not HTML escapes. As long as you have an editor that can save the template in the appropriate encoding, this should be fine:

```
@(item.fileID == "0" ? "" : "✔")
```

If you are stuck with ASCII only then you can use a C# string literal escape:

```
@(item.fileID == "0" ? "" : "\u2714")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work in Razor, even in older versions:

```cs
@(item.fileID == "0" ? "" : "✔")
```

If it's not, and you're getting garbled output (also called [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)), something's wrong with the page encoding.

First thing to verify is that the browser is interpreting the page as Unicode, either via the `Content-Type` HTTP response header or a `<meta charset=“utf-8”>` tag. The HTTP response header overrides any meta tag.

Second thing to verify is that your razor file (as well as any layouts) is saved with the UTF-8 encoding:

[image: Save with Encoding option in the Save File As dialog]

Then, save it as `Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001`.

Theoretically, `UTF-8 without signature` should work as well, but in my experimentation it required the signature / BOM, and most Visual Studio files seem to include the BOM anyway.